# Put variable in quotes in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-data-factory

I have declared a variable `vGetDate = 2021-03-20` and want to use this value in my query to fetch the record after that date. eg: (`select * from ABC where UpdatedDate > vGetDate`).

This query will not give the desired result as the Dates need to be in a single quote.

I can't touch the variable declaration part(vGetDate) in order to put the dates in quotes. I can manipulate the where condition but not sure how to put variables in quotes.

Comment: What you need is something like the PostgreSQL `quote_literal` function in order to defend against injection attack. I've asked about this before, and there isn't anything. It's a big gap, but the challenge with filling the gap is that different SQL dialects need different logic.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, you would do:

```
declare @date date;

set @date = '2021-03-20';

select *
from ABC
where UpdatedDate > @date;
```

If you are calling the SQL using an interface, you should be able to pass the parameter in when you are executing the query.

Comment: I am getting date variable from a job and value is not in quotes. I can't touch this variable and can't maually put quotes in this . I can make use of this variable and can create a new  variable with quotes but not sure how to do that . I want to utilize this value and compare it  against another date in order to fetch the data.

Comment: @SHIVAMYADAV . . . It is assigned to a parameter, presumably.  You can convert to a date time.

Comment: declare @date1 varchar(20) = activity.output(2021-03-22)
select * from abc  
where format([UpdatedDtTm],'yyyy-MM-dd')>cast(@LastPaymentProcessedDT as datetime)
I am using this but since date1 variable has date without quotes , thats why this where condition  is  not working fine

Comment: I don't think ADF has SQL parameters. All you can do is generate a string and pass it to SQL, and that opens the door to injection attacks. There is no `quote_literal` function.